# Is the data in header message automatically filled?

Tags: ros, pose, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am deciding between a Pose message and a Pose Stamped message: will I need to explicitly fill the header data for the stamped message or does ROS handle that automagically?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/79351/is-the-data-in-header-message-automatically-filled?/) by [benjaminabruzzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3131/benjaminabruzzo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2013-09-14

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The sequence number is filled. You will need to fill the rest as that actually determines the semantics of the message. ROS can't fill that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [benjaminabruzzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3131/benjaminabruzzo/) on 2013-09-14**:
For the standard header template I'll need to us a line such as: poseName.header.stamp = ros::Time::now(); and poseName.header.frame_id = #;  where # is some number of the associated frame?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-14**:
You'll use whatever is correct. The pose you send out will represent some pose relative to some frame, that is the frame_id to set. Wherever that comes from will also determine the time to set. This is the time that pose had relative to this frame, not when some calculation was made.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-14**:
frame_id and time stamp make sense in connection with tf. If you don't know how that works, check it out: http://wiki.ros.org/tf